# in C, how to use function from main program file in a shared library file

Tags: c, shared-libraries

c and i use it to generate  x.so shared library
in x.c i want to use few functions that are in the main module, (dir containing main files and exe), kind of recursive dependeny.
is there a way to do this (without copying those functions in x.c) ?
i read about -rdynamic , but could not get it fully.
when i compile i get 'somefunc' undeclared. (somefunc is in main module, i did extern somefunx in x.c but did not work)
please let me know 
thanks

Comment: What OS and compiler?  What did you do to try to use `somefunc()`?  You shouldn't have any trouble coming up with a version that's way trimmed down that you can post here.

Answer (score 2):

You could define the affected methods in your shared library to take the call back function pointer arguments, and then at call time pass the main module's functions as arguments. E.g.

```
// Library
void dosomething (int arg, void (*callback)(void)) { ... }

// Main module
void called_from_lib(void) { ... }

dosomething(10, called_from_lib);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like unix.  There is a function, dlopen(), that lets you dynamically call a function in a library - without referencing it at compile time and without linking it into the program.   dlopen() is POSIX, and so should be on any modern unix box.

Example here:

```
http://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/x172.html
```

There is also LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  This environment variable lets you use the same code, but allows you to substitute in a library that was not there at compile time.  This is not exactly what you are asking, but it can be made to do something along the lines of using adhoc shared libraries without resorting to dlopen.  Some systems like HPUX also support SHLIB_PATH which does the same thing.